# Take double integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I'm trying to take a double integral:

$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left[\left(\tilde{B_V}(\alpha_V) \{||\}(\tilde{B_V}(\alpha_V) > \tilde{B_A}(\alpha_A) - 1 - \theta(1 - r))Z\right) + \left(\tilde{B_A}(\alpha_A) -
 (1 - \theta(1 - r)Z)\right)\{||\}(\tilde{B_A}(\alpha_A) > \tilde{B_V}(\alpha_V) - 1 - \theta(1 - r))Z\right]$

In this case $\{||\}$ represents an indicator (or the `Boole` function in Mathematica).

This is my code:

```
$Assumptions =  \[Theta] > 0 && \[Theta] < 1 && \[Theta] \[Element] Reals
$Assumptions = $Assumptions && r > 0 && r < 1 && r \[Element] Reals
$Assumptions = $Assumptions && r > 0 && r < 1 && r \[Element] Reals
$Assumptions = $Assumptions && OverHat[\[Theta]] > 0 && OverHat[\[Theta]] < 1 && OverHat[\[Theta]] \[Element] Reals
$Assumptions = $Assumptions && Subscript[\[Alpha], A] > 0 && Subscript[\[Alpha], A] < 1 && Subscript[\[Alpha], A] \[Element] Reals
$Assumptions = $Assumptions && Subscript[\[Alpha], V] > 0 && Subscript[\[Alpha], V] < 1 && Subscript[\[Alpha], V] \[Element] Reals
OverTilde[Subscript[B, A]] := Subscript[\[Alpha], A] * \[Theta] * (1 - r)
OverTilde[Subscript[B, V]] := Subscript[\[Alpha], V] * OverHat[\[Theta]] * (1 - r)
Integrate[OverTilde[Subscript[B, V]][Subscript[\[Alpha], V]]*Boole[(OverTilde[Subscript[B, V]][Subscript[\[Alpha], V]] > OverTilde[Subscript[B, A]][Subscript[\[Alpha], A]] - 1 - \[Theta](1 - r))Z] + OverTilde[Subscript[B, A]][Subscript[\[Alpha], A]] - (1 - \[Theta](1 - r)Z)\right)*Boole[(OverTilde[Subscript[B, A]][Subscript[\[Alpha], A]] > OverTilde[Subscript[B, V]][Subscript[\[Alpha], V]] - 1 - \[Theta](1 - r))Z], {Subscript[\[Alpha], A], 0, 1}, {Subscript[\[Alpha], V], 0, 1}]
```

The output doesn't appear to be anything meaningful. Am I defining the functions and variables properly such that the integration occurs properly?

Comment: Sub- and superscripts in function definitions is a big no-no.

Comment: welcome! 1. in general it's good practice to modify [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) temporarily/locally as with `Block[{$Assumptions=<>},<>]` 2. eg `OverTilde[Subscript[B, A]] := Subscript[\[Alpha], A] * \[Theta] * (1 - r)` does not define a function in terms of `Subscript[\[Alpha], A] * \[Theta]` like `f[x_]:=x` defines a function `f` in terms of parameter `x`. 3. I think a bracket or parenthesis might be missing. If I were trying to solve this, I would not use subscripts etc but a more natural notation eg `otBA` for `OverTilde[Subscript[B, A]]`

Comment: Understood. I'll check out the assumptions and function documentation one more time.